# showing and hiding text box using php code

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to figure out how to hide a text box using php coding. I am using a form, which contains 3 radio buttons, and 3 text boxes as well. when the page is loaded, i only want the 3 radio buttons and the first 2 text boxes to appear, and the last text box to be hidden. when the user clicks the update radio button, the 2nd text box is hidden and the 3rd text box is visible. how would i accomplish this with this code?

with this code i am able to hide my text boxes. but is there a way to hide the text as well that is associated with the textbox that is being hidden?

```
<html>
<head><title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">

function show()
{
if (document.getElementById('ins').checked){

document.getElementById("zn").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("gpa").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("ngpa").style.display = "none";
}
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form action = "index.php" method = 'post'>
<input type="radio" name="group" id = "ins" onclick="show()" /> Insert Student <br />
<input type="radio" name="group" id = "upd" /> Update Student <br />
<input type="radio" name="group" id = "del" /> Delete Student <br />
Enter Z-number: <input type='text' name = 'z' maxlength='9' />
<br />Enter GPA: <input type='text' name='gpa' />
<br /> Enter new GPA: <input type="text" name ="ngpa" value ="false" />
<br /><input type='submit' value='Submit request' name='submit' />
</form>
<?php
 if (isset($_POST['z'])) {
 $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'jtinio', 'jtin666');
 if ($con) {
  mysql_select_db('jtinio', $con);

 $sql = "INSERT INTO Students VALUES (' ".$_POST['z']." ' , " .$_POST['gpa'].")";

 if (mysql_query($sql, $con)) echo 'Operation succeeded';
 else echo 'Not succeeded ' .mysql_error();




if (isset($_POST['ins'])) {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Students";
$res = mysql_query($sql, $con);

echo "<table border ='1'>";
echo "<tr><th>Znum</th><th>GPA</th></tr>";
while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
 echo "<tr><td>".$r['Znum']."</td></td>".$r['gpa']."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
}
mysql_close($con);
}
else {
echo 'Insertion failed'. 'Could not connect to DB.';}

}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have some sql injections in your query, escape those inputs! Plus validate empty stings and types(int or string), remove tags. I could say my gpa was `<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "http://evil.com/"</script>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP is server-based. What you want to do applies to user interaction (in the browser), so PHP is not the one to use for this purpose.

In a few words : **use JavaScript** (or jQuery)

Comment: if i were to use javascript, would i be able to incorporate that into my code?

Comment: All PHP does in this case, is to output the necessary HTML/CSS/JavaScript/whatever. So, yes, absolutely yes : you can integrate it the very same way you would if the page was static. :-)

Comment: @JohnTinio You're welcome my friend! :-) (for the benefit of the community if you think an answer is acceptable, please do *mark it* as an answer (the tick next to it)) ;-)

Comment: i am trying to write the javascript for it, but i can not seem to really figure it out. i will post my javascript code in.